# Ruby Rescue To Display Full Backtrace

Tags: ruby

Here's a real quick example:

```
puts File.join(nil, "hello")
```

Would output

```
test.rb:4:in 'join': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)
from test.rb:4
```

But when I do this:

```
begin
  puts File.join(nil, "hello")
rescue => exception
  puts exception.backtrace
end
```

This will output

```
test.rb:4:in 'join'
test.rb:4
```

Now how do I capture the full backtrace, including the "can't convert nil into String (TypeError)" part?

**@Sarah Vessels:**
In my specific code, this snippet:

```
puts "=============================="
puts error.message
puts "=============================="
puts error.inspect
puts "=============================="
puts error.backtrace
puts "=============================="
```

returns

```
==============================
exit
==============================
#<SystemExit: exit>
==============================
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/glib2.rb:37:in `exit'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/glib2.rb:37:in `exit_application'
multi.rb:234:in `main'
multi.rb:347
==============================
```

Comment: Following your edit, it looks like your rescue is catching a SystemExit exception (raised when you call exit) rather than the TypeError from trying to join nil with a String. What's on multi.rb line 234?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The value is stored there somewhere, based on this call to #inspect:

```
irb(main):001:0> begin
irb(main):002:1* puts File.join(nil, "Hello")
irb(main):003:1> rescue => exception
irb(main):004:1> puts exception.inspect
irb(main):005:1> end
#<TypeError: can't convert nil into String>
=> nil
```

[Exception#message](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Exception.html#M001312) is the descriptive part:

```
irb(main):006:0> begin
irb(main):007:1* puts File.join(nil, "hello")
irb(main):008:1> rescue => ex
irb(main):009:1> puts ex.message
irb(main):010:1> end
can't convert nil into String
=> nil
```

So to get the type of data you're looking for, you could do something like the following:

```
irb(main):015:0> begin
irb(main):016:1* puts File.join(nil, "hey")
irb(main):017:1> rescue => ex
irb(main):018:1> puts "#{ex.backtrace}: #{ex.message} (#{ex.class})"
irb(main):019:1> end
(irb):16:in `join'(irb):16:in `irb_binding'C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/workspace.rb
:52:in `irb_binding':0: can't convert nil into String (TypeError)
=> nil
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this =/ The code that I'm running is a ruby-gnome main loop so when it captures an error, it decides the error is from Gtk.main, not from line 234 in multi.rb. begin and rescue wraps around Gtk.main.

Answer (score 6):

@SaraVessels answer is closer to what you want, but I thought a ready-to-go alternative might help others, too.

For the scripties of us, ruby comes with two handy globals (well, *thread-global* I think), `$!` and `$@` which point to the last Exception and last Exceptions backtrace.

```
begin
  puts File.join(nil, "Hello")
rescue
  puts $! # ("no implicit ....")
  puts $@ # backtrace
end
```

will output:

```
no implicit conversion of nil into String
/tmp/e.rb:2:in `join'
/tmp/e.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

This is not very explicit, but handy in interactive or very prototypish settings.

Ruby stdlib includes the ['English'](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/English/rdoc/English.html) module (yes, uppercase), with which you could do

```
require "English" # capital-E!
# ...
  puts $ERROR_INFO     # $! ("no implicit ....")
  puts $ERROR_POSITION # $@ backtrace
# ...
```

Its weird and I never used it - but maybe somebody is happ(y|ier) with that.